# Compute area with Green's Theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, multiple-integral, greens-theorem

$\def\hl#1#2{\bbox[#1,1px]{#2}}
\def\box#1#2#3#4#5{\color{#2}{\bbox[0px, border: 2px solid #2]{\hl{#3}{\color{white}{\color{#3}{\boxed{\underline{\large\color{#1}{\text{#4}}}\\\color{#1}{#5}\\}}}}}}}
\def\verts#1{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}$
$\box{black}{black}{}
{Question}
{\text{Compute $\iint_S1dA$, where $S$ is the region between the x-axis and the curve }\\
\text{$g(t)=\begin{pmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1-\sin(t)\\1-\cos(t)\end{pmatrix}$ for $0\le t\le 2\pi$. (This curve is called a cycloid.)}}$

Let $Q=x$ and $P=0$, apply Green's Theorem we have
\begin{align}
\int_S 1-0~dA=\int_S\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}dA=&\int_{\partial S}Pdx+Qdy\\
=&\int_{\partial S}xdy\\
=&\int_0^{2\pi-\sin(2\pi)}0~dt+\int_{2\pi}^{0}(t-\sin(t))\sin(t)dt\\
=&3\pi
\end{align}
Is my solution correct ?

Comment: looks correct to me

Comment: I got $\pi$ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how you derived

\begin{align}
&\int_{\partial S}xdy\\
=&\int_0^{2\pi-\sin(2\pi)}0~dt+\int_{2\pi}^{0}(t-\sin(t))\sin(t)dt\\
\end{align}

I think it should be

\begin{align}
&\int_{\partial S}xdy\\
=&\int_{2\pi}^{0}(1-\sin t)\sin tdt\\
=&\pi
\end{align}

Also, note that the equation for the area of one arch of a cycloid equals $3\pi a^2$ only applys to $$x = a(\boldsymbol{\theta}-\sin \theta)$$
$$y = a(1-\cos \theta)$$